# Random different numbers android

Tags: android, random

```
                    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                list.add(i);
            }
            long seed = System.nanoTime();
            Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(seed));
            int number1 = list.remove(0);
            int number2 = list.remove(0);
            int number3 = list.remove(0);
            int number4 = list.remove(0);
            int number5 = list.remove(0);
            int number6 = list.remove(0);
            math.setText(number1 + "+" + number2);
            buttona.setText("" + (number1 + number2));
            buttonb.setText("" + (number3 + number4));
            buttonc.setText("" + (number5 + number6));
        }
```

I have this code, 6 different numbers between 1 to 10, but my problem is, I need the buttons text will be different, my code doesn't do it, for example:

Number1 = 3 , Number2 = 4, (7) ..

Number3 = 5 , Number4 = 2, (7) ..

How can I make all the texts be different?

Comment: your explanation is still not clear. So pl try to explain in bit detail. Also what error you are getting with current code as it is visible you are trying to change the button text and it should work.

Comment: http://www.7solutions.in/2013/06/how-to-generate-random-number-for.html

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I get no error, but sometimes the text on button 1 is equal to the text on button 2 or 3, and I don't want it to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set a random value to the `shuffle` function. Add a seed at the random and the output will be probably different :).

Try :

```
long seed = System.nanoTime();
Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(seed));
```

Comment: Can you see the edit and tell me if that what you meant?

Comment: I think yes, try and see anyway. :)

Comment: 2+3 = 5 AND 4+1=5 too. But i haven't used the same number ;). You can't have distinct value with your algorithm.